# Как изменить символ в TreeView C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы слева от корневого узла вместо "+" стоял треугольник? Понимаю, что встроенными средствами WinForms этого не сделать, а как это реализуется через WinAPI или события отрисовки?

Comment: Вот, согласитесь, лучше же стало выглядеть. Я даже лайк влеплю за это. Помните, что это не форум, а база знаний и в ваших же интересах сделать вопрос более дружелюбным для читателей, иначе большинство просто пройдут мимо, да еще и влепят минусы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно внешний вид `TreeView` в WinForms отрисовывается операционной системой. Но, если очень нужно, то можно при помощи свойства `DrawMode` сделать собственную отрисовку.

Для этого нужно установить для свойства `DrawMode` значение `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll` или `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText` и написать обработчик для события `DrawNode`.

Более подробную информацию можно найти в документации.

Документация Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawmode?view=netframework-4.8

Пример на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125131/treeview-change-plus-minus-icon

Answer (score 1):

Проблема уже решена, всем спасибо.

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hwnd, string pszSubAppName, string pszSubIdList);

...
SetWindowTheme(treeView1.Handle, "explorer", null);
```